# Displaying taxonomies as category links within sidebar and creating pages for these

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy

I've created a custom post type called 'work' for a portfolio section on the site I am working on at the moment. I have also registered the taxonomy 'workcategories' so that I can assign different pieces of work to different categories like:

Artists, Charities, Independents, International, Well Known

Which I have created via the WordPress Admin.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to display these terms as a list of links within my sidebar under the title 'Categories' and for these terms to link to archive pages displaying the work assigned to each.

At the moment I have this code in my index-work.php page to display ALL WORK:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=work&posts_per_page=4'); ?>
```

And I think I need to adapt this for my taxonomy pages. I've created a taxonomy-workcategories.php page for this purpose, but not sure if I actually have to create a separate page for each term listed above? Or can I use the taxonomy-workcategories.php all.

Any help much appreciated as I'm a bit lost. It's my first time working with taxonomies and I'm finding it all a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to create a separate template file for each taxonomy.

You can use the `wp_list_categories` function to create a list in your sidebar, [the Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Terms_in_a_custom_taxonomy) has a code example, but something like this should work:

```
<ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories('taxonomy=workcategories'); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I used the code from the Codex article and this works perfectly for listing my categories. thanks.

Comment: I also created a seperate template file for each taxonomy as it wouldn't work otherwise